# Error in adding list item to list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-deployment

```
One or more field types are not installed properly. 
Go to the list settings page to delete these fields
```

I got the above error while adding item to list, I Don't have any lookup Column and I also deleted relationship list.

Kindly Help....!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you trying to add item programiticaly or directly from site??

Comment: Was this list (or site) created from a template? If so, it's possible that the template is referring to site columns that cannot be found in the current site.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are adding the item by code. Just verify the column name spelled properly or not.

Comment: Problem resolved. I am handing itemadding event.but the column internal name is diffrent different later I changed column name to internal column name. Its Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

When ever Events are Handled.most of them used to give column name as it is there in list/library. But I recommend before providing the column make sure that column Name  and  its internal Name is same.

You can get Column internal Name by using [**SharePoint Manager Tool**](http://spm.codeplex.com/)